# How to get value of variable from other class?

Tags: java, variables

I have a public integer variable (MainReg) in my Counter Class. I want to get value of this variable and set it in my JComponent class. Here is piece of my JComponent class:

```
public class Komponent2 extends JComponent implements ActionListener
{
Counter counter3;
.
.
.
int a = counter3.valueOf(MainReg);
```

But it doesn't work. I tried also:

```
int a = valueOf(counter3.MainReg);
int a = counter3.valueOf(counter3.MainReg);
int a = counter3.MainReg;
```

But it still doesn't work. How can I get this variable? Thanks for helping me.

EDIT

Here is my Counter class:

```
 import java.util.Observable ;
public class Counter extends Observable
{
    public int MainReg;
    public int CompareReg;
    public Mode countMode;
    public boolean OVF;
    private int a=0;

public Counter()
  {
    OVF=false;
  }
public void setCompareReg(int dana)
  {
    CompareReg=dana;
  }
public void setMainReg(int dana2)
  {
    MainReg=dana2;
  }
public void setMode(Mode countMode)
  {
    this.countMode=countMode;
  }
public void Count()
  {
   if (countMode==Mode.UP)
   {
    MainReg++;
    OVF=false;
    if (CompareReg < MainReg)
    {
     OVF=true;
     MainReg=0;
     setChanged();
     notifyObservers();
    }
   }
   else if (countMode==Mode.UPDOWN)
   {     
    if(MainReg >= CompareReg)
    {
     a=MainReg;     
     MainReg--;
     OVF=true;
    }
    else
    {
     if(MainReg >= a)
     {
      MainReg++;
      OVF=false;
     }
     else
     {
      MainReg--;
      if(MainReg==0)
      {
       a=0;
      }
      OVF=false;
     }
    }
   }
   else if (countMode==Mode.CONTINOUS)
   {
    MainReg++;
    OVF=false;
    if (65536 < MainReg)
    {
     MainReg=0;
     OVF=true;
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: You don't show us your Counter class, so it's hard to answer your question. Does it have a `valueOf(...)` method? And what exactly are you passing into this method? It almost looks as if you're making code up by wishful thinking (which usually doesn't work very well). Does it have a getter method for the value(s) it holds? Those are what should be called.

Comment: "Doesn't work". You get an error? A nullpointer, because the counter is not initialized? A method not found because there is no valueof method?

Comment: Oi oi! Firstly, using public properties is not recommended. Secondly, having public properties and getters/setters for them is redundant.

Comment: Find a textbook on Java programming and study it.

Comment: using upper case variables is not recommended, nor are variables starting with an upper case. This is Java after all.

Answer (score 1):

Well I see two ways you can do this.

1. Your MainReg integer is public, you could simply use int i = counter3.MainReg;
2. Or you could create a getMainReg() method in your Counter class.  Then call it from whatever class.

   EX:

   public int getMainReg() {
         return this.MainReg;
      }

Answer (score 0):

Give your Counter class getter methods, and then call them when you need to access their values. i.e.,

```
public int getMainReg() {
   return mainReg;
}
public int getCompareReg(){
   return compareReg;
}
public Mode getCountMode() {
   return countMode;
}
```

And make your fields all private. Also your code should obey Java naming rules: variable names should begin with lower-case letters.

Also be sure that you've initialized your counter variable in the class that uses it, either by creating a new instance, or if appropriate, passing in a valid instance in a constructor or method parameter.

Comment: I will be grateful if you tell me how to do it.

Comment: @Martyn: see edit. But whatever you do, don't try to make up methods that just don't exist for that way lies insanity.